# Mysql Insert по условию

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток. В общем, есть у меня такая необходимость:
Имеется таблица:

**id, operator, stantion, data, errors, file**

Суть заключается в чем - оператор (а их несколько) добавляет файл, и нужно занести это все в табличку. Каждый файл с определенной станции - столбец stantion, и вся загвоздка в том, что нужно заносить в таблицу УНИКАЛЬНЫЕ значения stantion ЗА ДЕНЬ. Т.е если оператор почему-то выгрузил отчет по одной и той-же станции за день два раза, мы второй раз это не пишем в БД. Пытался сделать как:

```
INSERT INTO import_file (`operator`,`stantion`,`data`,`errors`,`file`) VALUES ('$operator', '$stantion', '$data') WHERE ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM import_file WHERE `data`='$data' AND `stantion`='$stantion' AND `operator`='$operator') = 0)
```

Естественно, ничего хорошего, кроме ругани MySQL не получил. Может что-то делаю не так, может я изобретаю велосипед, и для этого есть како-то стандартизированное решение?

Comment: А почему не сделать валидацию на уровне пхп? Проверить есть ли уже запись - если да - то вернут какое то сообщение пользователю, если нет - ну тогда записать в базу данные.

Answer (score 4):

Можно примерно так:

```
INSERT INTO import_file (`operator`,`stantion`,`data`,`errors`,`file`)
  select '$operator', '$stantion', '$data'
    from (select 1) X
   WHERE not exists(SELECT 1 FROM import_file
                     WHERE `data`='$data' AND `stantion`='$stantion'
                       AND `operator`='$operator'
                   )
```

Или сделайте уникальный индекс по полям data, stantion, operator и попытка вставки дубля в таблицу вернет ошибку, которую вы можете проанализировать и понять что запись была или воспользоваться конструкцией `on duplicate key    update`.

НО, вы подставляете значения переменных непосредственно в запрос, что приводит к массе проблем и уязвимостей (до половины всех взломов сайтов в интернете происходят именно по этой причине). Поэтому *никогда* ни одной переменной непосредственно в текст запроса не подставляйте. Вместо этого используйте подготавливаемые запросы и привязку значений ([bind_param](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindparam.php)).

Answer (score 2):

В общем виде:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM import_file  WHERE stantion =  $stantion;

if(!total){
    INSERT ...
}else{ 
    UPDATE ...
}
```

Естественно, как отметил @Moonvvell, это в файле модели (или где вы отправляете запросы).

Comment: Ну это все здорово, просто 2 запроса - какбэ, а хотелось лаконичности... Ну скорее всего так и придется делать - сначала смотреть есть-ли записи по критериям в БД, а потом добавлять

Comment: ну какбэ, да :)